# Sublime Text editor layout missing display window for folders

Tags: sublimetext

I am using Sublime to follow along for a python tutorial yet I am seeing only a blank Sublime page. When I used to use Sublime the layout had a window on the left hand side of the screen that showed the open folders and other folders and the ability to create folders and create files. I am wondering if newer versions of Sublime do not show that information? Are such features available only to people who get a subscription? I do not want to buy a subscription unless I know I will get these features.

Thanks for the help.

I downloaded another version and tried it, but the view was the same.

Comment: **`View -> Side Bar -> Show Side Bar`**